# How can I output data from a vector to a text file

Tags: rust

Good afternoon!
I have some configured vector by type:

```
let v = vec!["foo", "bar", "go", "any"];
```

How can I output the contents of a vector to a text file with the addition of something to the line?

What I want to get in the text file:

```
foo@gmail.com
bar@gmail.com
go@gmail.com
any@gmail.com
```

Options I have tried:

```
use std::{fs::File, io::Write};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let v = vec!["foo", "bar", "go", "any"];

    let mut f = File::create("try.txt")?;

    for item in v {
        f.write_all(item.as_bytes())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

The final code looked like this:

```
use std::{fs::File, io, io::Write};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let v = vec!["foo", "bar", "go", "any"];
    let mut write_domain = String::new();
    println!("Enter your domain :");

    let _user_domain = io::stdin().read_line(&mut write_domain).unwrap();

    let mut f = File::create("try.txt")?;

    for item in v {
            let item = format!("{item}@{write_domain}");
            f.write_all(item.as_bytes())?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

What a high ego people have, be kinder.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You don't know how to open a file? How to write to it? Those questions are very well documented. Did you do any research prior to asking this question?

Comment: my problem is that I cannot write data like 'str' to a vector using methods like .write_all()

Comment: Well you should show your current "problematic" implementation, it would be a better starting point for us to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler if you joined the vector first into one string and then write it all at once :

```rs
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{stdin, Write};

fn main() {
    let emails = vec!["foo", "bar", "go", "any"];

    let mut write_domain = String::new();

    stdin().read_line(&mut write_domain).unwrap();

    let text = emails
        .iter()
        .map(|name| format!("{name}@{write_domain}"))
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
        .join("\n");

    let mut f = File::create("try.txt").unwrap();

    f.write_all(text.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```